# Is $0$ a imaginary number?

Tags: complex-numbers

I was using Euler's formula $ e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ with the case when $ x = 2\pi$.
$$ e^{i2\pi} = \cos(2\pi) + i\sin(2\pi) = 1 + 0i $$
So I end up with the identity $ e^{i2\pi} = 1$. Now, if I apply $\ln$ it goes $$ \ln e^{i2\pi}=\ln1$$ $$ i2\pi = \ln1$$
How $\ln1=0$, Should be that $i2\pi=0$ its true, or not? The first implication I found its that you can divide any imaginary number by zero. $$ {ai\over 0} = {ai\over i2\pi} = {a\over 2\pi}$$
What don you think?

Comment: The real part is $0$, so it's purely imaginary.  Also real, of course.

Comment: Once you enter the complex realm, the logarithm becomes a multi-valued function. (See Wikipedia's ["Complex logarithm" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).) So, you cannot go from $e^{i2\pi}=1$ to $i2\pi=0$.

Comment: @Blue But why you can go from $ e^{i\pi} = -1 $ to $ {i\pi} = \ln -1 $?

Comment: Who says that you can?  You may be confusing $\text{Ln}$ with $\ln$ or you may be confusing what domain or standard representations are allowed when discussing $\ln$.  You've seen how $\sqrt{x^2}$ doesn't necessarily equal $x$, right?  (*for example $\sqrt{(-2)^2}=2\neq -2$*)  Or how $\arcsin(\sin(\theta))$ doesn't necessarily equal $\theta$?  (*for example $\arcsin(\sin(6\pi))=0\neq 6\pi$*).  Something similar is happening here.

Comment: Just because $e^a = e^b$ for complex numbers that doesn't mean that $a=b$.  In particular just becaues $e^{2\pi i}=e^0$ that doesn't mean that $2\pi i = 0$.  They are most certainly different numbers.  As for $\ln(e^z)$ compared to $z$, as above these are not necessarily the same.  If talking about $\text{Ln}$, the principal logarithm, this will only be true when $z$ is in a certain range of values, $2\pi i$ falls outside of that range, but $0$ lies within it.

Comment: oh, i didnt know that Ln and ln where different. So its just about the formalization.

Comment: Yes, thanks. @Blue

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that there is a function $\ln\colon\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ such that, if $z\in\Bbb C$, $\ln\bigl(e^z\bigr)=z$. But there is no such function.

Comment: But if $\ln(-1) = i\pi$ and $i\pi$ es a imaginary number. Why there isnt?

Comment: What does $\ln(-1)$ mean?